# REVTeX4-1 biblography problems

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, revtex

My co-author and me have decided to send a paper to the Journal of Mathematical Physics which is a publication of American Institute of Physics. Being a junior co-author I got the dirty job of converting our .tex documents written in

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
```

into

REVTeX4.1 in particular to

```
\documentclass[aip,jmp]{revtex4-1}
```

REVTeX4.1 uses natbib for bibliography and my first problem is that on this machine I do not have new enough version of natbib (this machine is overdue for 
OS and package update)

```
LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 7549, version
               `2009/11/07 8.31a (PWD, AO)' of package natbib,
               but only version
               `2009/07/16 8.31 (PWD, AO)'
               is available.
```

Compilation with sequence

```
pdflatex filename.tex 
bibtex   filename 
pdflatex filename.tex 
pdflatex filename.tex
```

produces expected output PDF output but returns a bunch of errors starting with

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `LastBibItem' on page 2 undefined on input line 9.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \@bibitemShut 

l.62   {Slawny}(1986)}]{HLS:ppm}
                                %
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \@bibitemShut 

l.72 ...[{\citenamefont {Onitsuka}(2011)}]{MO:ppm}
                                                  %
```

Can anyone who is more familiar with REVTeX give me a quick hint what is wrong besides outdated version of natbib?

By the way even though Journal requires bibliography to be a part of the single tex file (commands input are not allowed for the final submission) I was using

```
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{asymptotically_minimal_uncertainty}
```

as provide in the template file by Journal.

By the way for people who are curious the final markup at least for the Journal of Mathematical Physics is XML. So they are not really using TeX.

Comment: I can't answer this, but I do sympathise. I'm desperate to stop using BibTeX in favour of biber, but I'm tied to it because the journals tie me to REVTeX.

Comment: @Predrag A lot of journals use some form of XML storage, whether they accept LaTeX sources or not. So it's all about having scripts which convert input (Word, `.tex`, something else) into clean XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted in question I had a hunch that the problem is in fonts and is related to the obsolete version of TeXLive I was using. Indeed on this freshly installed machine which uses TeXLive 2011 stable there are no compilation errors.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to convert your file to revtex4-1. If it compiles properly it will be considered for peer review.
The revtex4-1 package is meant to help those authors who need that sort of guidance. The sub-styles are nice and will give you an approximate view of what the article should look like in print.
Let me know if you would like someone to look your files over before you submit.
Thanks,
Brian G.

Comment: I have found the most likely reason your out of date version of TexLive was giving you this problem.
REvtex4-1 requires the latest version of NATBIB (8.3b), the older versions do not support the BIBSHUT command.