# BibTeX, Natbib, and Algorithm2e

Tags: bibtex, natbib, algorithm2e

I'm trying to prepare a journal submission, and I'm having trouble getting natbib to play nicely.

1. When I include `natbib` in my document, it gives me the following error:

   ```
   ! Undefined control sequence
   \chapter ...ace{10\p@ }}\algocf@original@chapter

   l.1 \begin{thebibliography}{17}
   ```

   This isn't such a huge deal to me -- I'm fine working around it.  The bigger problem that I have is...
2. When I disable `natbib`, the citation keys and references look horrible.  For example, if I have the following `bibtex` entry

   ```
   @article{Day06,
       author = {T.E.~Day and J.T.~Napoli and P.C.~Kuo},
       title = {Scheduling the Resident 80-Hour Work Week: An Operations Research Algorithm},
       journal = {Current Surgery},
       volume = {63},
       number = {2},
       month = {Mar.-Apr.},
       year = {2006},
       pages = {136-141}
   }
   ```

   whenever I use `\cite{Day06}` it produces [Day et al(2006)Day, Napoli, and Kuo] in my text, which looks awful.  Even worse, the entry in the references section looks terrible, too:

   > [Day et al(2006)Day, Napoli, and Kuo] Day T, Napoli J, Kuo P (2006)
   >   Scheduling the resident 80-hour work week: An operations research
   >   algorithm.  Current Surgery 63(2):136-141

   I don't know why it's including the (horribly-mangled) key in the citation next to the author list.

Any suggestions?  Has anyone else dealt with this before?

**Edited** to more accurately reflect the problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) The error message seems to point to something regarding the `algorithm2e` package. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Have a look at [plainnat.bst without natbib](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14938)

Comment: Ah -- yes, it was a problem with algorithm2e, it had nothing to do with the Springer format.  The link from @lockstep had the key -- loading algorithm2e after natbib resolved it.  I hadn't noticed before, because I just happened to always load natbib first, but when I copied into the Springer format, I switched the order.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using MiKTeX or TeXLive? If you are using TeXLive can you tell me which version? To be frank it looks very similar to the fonts problem I had with natbib due to the outdated (2009) version of TeXLive I used. I updated to 2011 and the problems went a way.

Please check out the answer to [REVTeX4-1 biblography problems](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46423/revtex4-1-biblography-problems/47296#47296).